# Can I use Storyboard in a group project?

Tags: ios, swift, github, xcode-storyboard

This is my first Question on stack overflow so please be gentle to me.

A friend of mine and me are working on an IOS-App together.
We both use Xcode Version 14.0 and Swift Version 5.7.

Now we have a problem since he is working with Storyboard and when I pull the repository from Github the Storyboards don't have any content, although they should!
I am trying to build the backend for the app but somehow I am not able to get this Storyboard problem together.

We don't have an Apple-Developer license but hopefully this does not interfere with something.

We already tried sending the Storyboards via Whatsapp in a Zip but that also didn't work.
I think this is not only a problem between Git and Storyboard but Storyboard in general.

Comment: From your description, I think maybe you forget to push ``.xcodeproj`` which is ``.pbxproj``.

Comment: i do have a **.xcodeproj**  File but not a **.pbxproj** File where should i technically find this file? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It's your ``.xcodeproj`` if you push ``.xcodeproj`` it is included. Remember to push your ``.storyboard`` too.

Comment: Did not help, sadly we probably have to change from **.storyboard** to something like **Xib**

Comment: I solved the problem. My friend had more than 1 repo connected to the project in Xcode. We setup a new Github-Repo, and created a new project and slowly copied everything from one project into the other one.